# _react2.fireEvent.change is not a function | react testing library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, input, react-testing-library

I try to simulate onChange with fireEvent.change, but get error _react2.fireEvent.change is not a function.

I checked official docs of react testing library, did everything exactly how it's there https://testing-library.com/docs/example-input-event, even created another test where copied all code from docs, and created exactly the same input in react component. Still the same - _react2.fireEvent.change is not a function.

My input

```
<input
  data-testid='input-file'
  value={img}
  onChange={upImage}
  className="file-upload"
  type="file"
/>
```

my Test

```
it('img preview', () => {
  const form = render(<Form addItem={func} />)

  const input = form.getByTestId('input-file')
  const file = new File(['dummy content'], 'example.png',  {type: 'image/png'})

  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: { file } } })
})
```

also, when I check input in test, in console it's showed like this:

```
 Received: <input class="file-upload" data-testid="input-file" type="file" value="" />
```

there is simply not onChange

Comment: also, I tried in another project, and everything works fine

Comment: How are you importing `fireEvent`?